# Flutter Not able to close keyboard on app start if it's visible for any reason when the app launches

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Not able to dismiss the keyboard on app start. A demo is given below.[image]

have tried following in the build method of the first widget of MaterialApp after launch and in the initState method but non worked:

1.

```
final FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus && currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!.unfocus();
}
```

2. 

```
final FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
    currentFocus.unfocus();
}
```

3. 

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

Comment: Have you tried `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());`? Have you tried wrapping any of this in a delay to test for timing issues?

Comment: @daddygames's suggestions should solve your issue. Also it seems like your attached screenshot is not relevant to the question?

Comment: the screenshot is absolutely relevant since it is one of the case that the keyboard is visible on app launch.

Comment: @daddygames tried your suggestion as well didn't work either.

Comment: is it happening on emulator or on real device too? also is it happening even on first run or not?

Comment: happening on emulator(Android api 32) haven't checked on a real device. Basically, on the first run it would work fine on the emulator since the emulator doesn't have any performance limits but in some cases the real device lacs memory and there are cases that the keyboard opened for some other app remains open even on switching app.

Answer (score -1):

try to wrap your bg with GestureDetector and try it

```
onTap: ()=>FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the keyboard is open before the launch

Answer (score -1):

This works for me. I only tested in android.

```
SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the keyboard is open before the launch